# recursively remove undefined from object (including parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a solution to a problem where I need to remove undefined from nested object including all parents if there are no values there, please consider example:

```
var test = {
  foo : {
    bar : {
      baz : undefined
    }
  },
  bar : 1
}
```

So my task is to remove baz along with bar and foo but still have bar at the root level;
I know that it's trivial task to solve with 2 for loops, I'm just wondering if there are more elegant and clean solutions which will use recursive stack instead?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: so, the desired result is `{bar: 1}`?

Comment: @georg yes, exactly

Comment: One tricky bit here is knowing which "empty" objects to remove. For instance, some built-in objects (like `Date`) have no own, enumerable properties. Should they be removed? And if not, how do you know whether you can remove an empty object? Only remove ones that are directly inheriting from `Object`? Other than that, my gut is that depth-first recursion should be able to handle it in a single recursive pass...

Comment: In my case there won't be any built-in objects like Date @T.J.Crowder

Comment: try something like this. this https://jsfiddle.net/2kddkoqh/ (not the best way to do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depth-first recursion should be able to handle it:

```
function cleanse(obj, path) {
    for (const key of allOwnKeys(obj)) {
        // Get this value and its type
        const value = obj[key];
        const type = typeof value;
        if (type === "object" && value !== null) {
            // Recurse...
            cleanse(value);
            // ...and remove if now "empty"
            if (objectIsEmpty(value)) {
                delete obj[key]
            }
        } else if (type === "undefined") {
            // Undefined, remove it
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
}

function allOwnKeys(obj) {
    return [
        ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj),
        ...Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)
    ];
}

function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
    // NOTE: insert your definition of "empty" here, here's a starting point:
    if (    (obj instanceof Date) ||
            (obj instanceof Map && obj.size) ||
            (obj instanceof Set && obj.size) ||
            (obj instanceof WeakSet) || // You have to assume it's not empty
            (obj instanceof WeakMap)    // same
            // ... allow for String, Number, Boolean? ...
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return (
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0 &&
        Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).length === 0
    );
}
```

I've used `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` to find all of the object's own properties because the more commonly-used `Object.keys` only checks for *own, enumerable* properties with string names, not inherited properties, non-enumerable ones, or Symbol-named ones.

Re *"insert your definition of "empty" here"*:

1. The special cases in `objectIsEmpty` are there because `Date`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet` objects don't have any own properties by default, but that doesn't necessarily mean they're empty. For `Map` and `Set` we can look at their `size` property to see if they have any elements in them; `Date` you probably always want to keep; for `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet`, you can't check if they have anything in them, so I'd assume you should keep them. Adjust `objectIsEmpty` to suit your needs, and note that you may want to update it as JavaScript continues to evolve.
2. The code above doesn't try to handle `Proxy` objects in any special way.
3. Although they're rarely used (and should never be used), there *are* object versions of strings, numbers, and booleans (`value instanceof String`, etc.); they also don't have any own, enumerable properties by default. I haven't bothered with them above because they shouldn't be used in the first place.

Example:

```js
const test = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            baz: undefined,
        },
    },
    bar: 1,
};
cleanse(test);
display(test);

const test2 = {
    a: {
        aa: {
            aaa: undefined,
        },
    },
    b: 1,
    c: {
        [Symbol()]: undefined,
    },
    d: {
        date: new Date(),
    },
    e: {
        emptyMap: new Map(),
    },
    f: {
        nonEmptyMap: new Map([["a", 1]]),
    },
};
cleanse(test2);
display(test2);

function cleanse(obj, path) {
    for (const key of allOwnKeys(obj)) {
        // Get this value and its type
        const value = obj[key];
        const type = typeof value;
        if (type === "object" && value !== null) {
            // Recurse...
            cleanse(value);
            // ...and remove if now "empty"
            if (objectIsEmpty(value)) {
                delete obj[key]
            }
        } else if (type === "undefined") {
            // Undefined, remove it
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
}

function allOwnKeys(obj) {
    return [
        ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj),
        ...Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)
    ];
}

function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
    // NOTE: insert your definition of "empty" here, here's a starting point:
    if (    (obj instanceof Date) ||
            (obj instanceof Map && obj.size) ||
            (obj instanceof Set && obj.size) ||
            (obj instanceof WeakSet) || // You have to assume it's not empty
            (obj instanceof WeakMap)    // same
            // ... allow for String, Number, Boolean? ...
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return (
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0 &&
        Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).length === 0
    );
}

function display(obj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(
        obj,
        (key, value) => {
            if (value instanceof Map || value instanceof Set) {
                return [...value];
            }
            return value;
        },
        4
    ));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for the Depth-first recursion, unfortunately can't upvote yet

Comment: Note that the above code is a bit buggy.  For example, if you pass in an object `{modifiedAt: new Date()}`, it will decide that the date is an object without a length of 0 and delete it

Comment: @PeterEhrlich - Hence *"NOTE: insert your definition of "empty" here"* but yeah, I've beefed that up a bit and modernized the answer some. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Below example can help you get started.

**Without delete keys with empty values:**

```js
var test = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: undefined,
      bar: {
        baz: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  bar: 1,
  baz: undefined
}

function loop(obj) {
  var t = obj;
  for (var v in t) {
    if (typeof t[v] == "object")
      loop(t[v]);
    else if (t[v] == undefined)
      delete t[v];
  }
  return t;
}

var output = loop(test);

console.log(output);
```

**Deleting keys with empty values:**

```js
var test = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: undefined,
      bar: {
        baz: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  bar: 1,
  baz: undefined
}

function loop(obj) {
  var t = obj;
  for (var v in t) {
    if (typeof t[v] == "object")
      if (!t[v].length)
        delete t[v];
      else
        loop(t[v]);
    else if (t[v] == undefined)
      delete t[v];
  }
  return t;
}

var output = loop(test);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This does nothing to remove the empty objects.

Comment: Now it does, but incorrectly. Objects don't have a `length` property (in the general case). The above only seems to work because it **happens** there are no non-blank objects except the top level. It would remove any object without a `length` property.

Comment: Also note that this will attempt to delete properties owned by an object's prototype, which will (silently) fail. You can only delete a property from the object itself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks. I'm new to objects and arrays. Will check on that.

Answer (score 3):

IMO this is much cleaner but probably a smidge slower

```js
const cleanUndefined = object => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
const testWithoutUndefined = cleanUndefined(test)
```

Comment: Usually you're just working with relatively simple data though so would this not be enough in those cases?

Comment: worked well for my use-case w/ simple data. +1 for being clean and minimal

Answer (score 1):

I took the function proposed by @T.J. Crowder and changed it to use `for ... of` and `Object.entries(obj)`. I also return the object for convenience.

```
function cleanseObject(obj) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            cleanseObject(value)
            if (!Object.keys(value).length) delete obj[key]
        } else if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            delete obj[key]
        }
    }

    return obj
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without mutating the original object**

```js
const cleanse = obj => {
  const newObj = Array.isArray(obj) ? [...obj] : { ...obj };
  Object.keys(newObj).forEach((key) => {
    // Get this value and its type
    const value = newObj[key];
    var type = typeof value;
    if (type === "object") {
      // Recurse...
      newObj[key] = cleanse(value);
      // ...and remove if now "empty" (NOTE: insert your definition of "empty" here)
      if (!Object.keys(value).length) {
        delete newObj[key]
      }
    }
    else if (type === "undefined") {
      // Undefined, remove it
      delete newObj[key];
    }
  });
  return newObj;
};

console.log(
    cleanse({ a: { b: undefined, c: 22 }}),
    cleanse({ a: [{ b: undefined, c: 22 }] }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleanPayload(obj: any) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const value = obj[key];
    const type = typeof value;
    if (!value || !type) {
      delete obj[key];
    } else if (type === 'object') {
      cleanPayload(value);
      if (!Object.keys(value).length) {
        if (key != 'attributes') {
          delete obj[key];
        }
      }
    } 
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code, which will also remove that undefined contained key and empty object from the main object.

```js
var test = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: undefined,
      bar: {
        baz: undefined,
      }
    }
  },
  bar: 1,
  baz: undefined
}

function loop(obj) {
  var t = obj;

  for (var v in t) {
      if (typeof t[v] == "object"){
         loop(t[v]);
         if(!Object.keys(t[v]).length){  
            delete t[v];
         }
      } else if (t[v] == undefined){
        delete t[v];
      }
   }
 
  return t;
}

var output = loop(test);
console.log(output);
```